# How to return number of decimal places in context of trailing zeros

Tags: r, char, type-conversion

A nuance on this question: [how to return number of decimal places in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173692/how-to-return-number-of-decimal-places-in-r)

**How can I count the number of digits after the decimal when there are trailing zeros?**

Using the function in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5173906/2651663) :

```
decimalplaces <- function(x) {
  if ((x %% 1) != 0) {
    nchar(strsplit(sub('0+$', '', as.character(x)), ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][[2]])
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}
```

The goal is to yield a count that includes zeros

With the existing function it ignores trailing zeros, e.g.:

```
 > decimalplaces(10)
[1] 0
> decimalplaces(10.0)
[1] 0
> decimalplaces(10.00)
[1] 0
```

Should return 0, 1, and 2 for the examples above.

Comment: `x %% 1` equals 0 for your examples

Comment: I think you have to specify the variable type as character when reading the data from your file / database

Comment: @Niko I think I have two problems now :) The source is a MySQL database and even with CAST(x, as CHAR) it yields the column field decimals as set in the database, not what is necessarily desired.

Comment: I think your SQL database does not store the trailing zeros at all if the field is numeric (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028688/trailing-zeroes-not-going-into-database). 

I think you would have to change the column type in your database to string if you really need the trailing zeros.

Comment: @Niko  Thanks, the zeros are there, it's just that there are too many for some data when using CAST.  The column is a decimal (10,3). Different data have zero, one, two, or three decimal places.  I'm trying to maintain that precision with calculations.  I guess I have a different question to ask...