# show double digit numbers in count below 10?

Tags: php, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zero-pad digits in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324358/zero-pad-digits-in-string)

I'm using this count script to show the number of new messages a user has. the script shows a number value of however many new messages the user has by using count.

At the moment if the number is below 10 the number will be show as 1, 2, 3 etc but i want it to be show as 01, 02, 03, 04 etc in double digits.

Is this possible. Here's the code i have so far?

```
<?php
$check_new_messages_set = check_new_messages();
while ($new = mysql_fetch_array($check_new_messages_set)) {

echo "<div class=\"msg-notify\">". $new['COUNT(id)'] ."</div>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf) for simple padding:

```
$padded = sprintf('%02d', $number); // 2 -> 02
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is str_pad, either way you're going to end up with a string but if its just for display that's not a problem