# Minutes to Hours : Minutes

Tags: php, function

I am currently converting minutes to hours & minutes by using this function:

```
function minToHourMin($time) {
    $minutes = $time%60;
    $hours = floor($time/60);
    return $hours . ':' . $minutes;
}
```

However, it doesn't work as expected when displaying the minutes that are < 10.

For example running the function with 61 minutes would return:

1:1 instead of the intended 1:01

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with converting, but everything to do with converting the number to the appropriate string. Use `sprintf` with the `%02d` format specifier. Make sure to focus on the real problem and remove unnecessary context.

Comment: or `str_pad($minutes, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: Thanks! The return line is now: return sprintf('%2d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zero-pad digits in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324358/zero-pad-digits-in-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it all at once:

```
return sprintf('%02d:%02d', floor($time/60), $time%60);
```

Comment: Yep, looks cleaner. Changing %02d to %2d for the hours returns what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You need

> sprintf('%08d', $minutes);

So the function would be

```
function minToHourMin($time) {
    $minutes = $time%60;
    $minutes = sprintf('%08d', $minutes);
    $hours = floor($time/60);
    return $hours . ':' . $minutes;
}
```