# How format number value in php?

Tags: php

I want format number as style '00000' ex:

```
$a=1 => $a2="00001"
$b=23 => $b2="00023"
```

How format number in php?

Comment: you can use `str_pad` function, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zero-pad digits in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324358/zero-pad-digits-in-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use str_pad : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

```
$formattedValue = str_pad($value, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/sprintf):

```
$formattedValue = sprintf('%05s', $value);
```

- `0` is the character to pad `5` times. `s` specifies that it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

use the str_pad function:-
    $a2 = str_pad($a, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);