# PHP - Rename pictures sequentially double digit

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code to rename pictures sequentially:

```
function sequentialImages($path) {
 $i = 1;
 $files = glob($path."/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png}",GLOB_BRACE|GLOB_NOSORT);
  $count = count($files);
 foreach ( $files as $file ) {
  $newname = str_pad($i, strlen($count)+1, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $ext = substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1);
  $newname = $path.'/pictures'.$newname.'.'.$ext;
  if ( $file != $newname ) {
   rename($file, $newname);  
  }
  $i++;
 }
}
```

I would like to rename

```
01.jpg to picture01.jpg
02.jpg to picture02.jpg
03.jpg to picture03.jpg
04.jpg to picture04.jpg
.....
10.jpg to picture10.jpg
11.jpg to picture11.jpg
```

The output I am getting is

```
pictures001.jpg
pictures002.jpg
pictures003.jpg
pictures004.jpg
....
pictures010.jpg
pictures011.jpg
```

I would like that if the image sequence is less than 9 it will have a '0' before it. If it is 10 or more it won't have that extra zero.

I tried adding

```
for ($i=1; $i<=21; $i++)  {
    if($i<=9) {
        //code
    }
    else {
        //code
    }
}
```

but it didn't work either.

Comment: use `sprintf("%02d", $i)` instead of str_pad. More info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324358/zero-pad-digits-in-string

Comment: what if you have more than 99 files?

Comment: @Kryten http://codepad.viper-7.com/s07gbf

Comment: @LozCherone I know your solution will work (that's the way I'd do it), I'm just wondering why he's limiting himself to <100 files. I certainly have a LOT more images than that on my hard drive :-)

Comment: Oh right, I though it was pointed at me ;p

Comment: Have you considered leveraging command line (shell commands) for this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `str_pad` **and** you are staying under 99 files, then you should hardcode the length you want to pad to.

```
$newname = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Of course, as Loz Cherone correctly mentioned, the better way to do this is to use `sprintf`.

```
sprintf("%02d", $i)
```