# Padding numbers in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP code which creates Arrays of A-MTP-1-1, A-MTP-1-2, etc....

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {           # Pass 3 as you need three sets
    foreach (range(1, 12) as $val) {    # 1,12 again as per your requirements
        $arr[] = "A-MTP-$i-" . $val;

    }
}
foreach (array_chunk($arr, 4) as $k => $arr1) {    # Loop the array chunks and set a key
    $finarray["ch" . ($k + 1)] = $arr1;
}
extract($finarray);   # Use the extract on that array so you can access each array separately
print_r($ch9);        # For printing the $ch9 as you requested.
?>
```

I need the arrays to have a 0 infront of the single digit numbers so it would become A-MTP-01-01, A-MTP-01-02, etc... but not have a zero when it gets to the double digit numbers.

How can I achieve what I need as I have tried the following and it's made no change:

```
for ($i = 01; $i <= 12; $i++) {           # Pass 3 as you need three sets
    foreach (range(01, 12) as $val) {    # 1,12 again as per your requirements
        $arr[] = "A-MTP-$i-" . $val;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zero-pad digits in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324358/zero-pad-digits-in-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) is your friend.

So this line
`$arr[] = "A-MTP-$i-" . $val;`

would change to this
`$arr[] = sprintf("A-MTP-%02d-%02d", $i, $val);`

Comment: Dang, you beat me to the punch!  Good lookin' code though... exactly the same as mine :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you should use [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) as follows:

```
$arr[] = sprintf("A-MTP-%02d-%02d", $i, $val);
```