# PHP - Add leading zeros to number but keep maximum length

Tags: php

I have an Auto-Increment field in a database.

I want these numbers to be prepended by zeros, to a maximum length of seven.

Example:

> Original number: 1  Desired result: 0000001

or

> Original number 768 Desired result 0000768

How would I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zero-pad digits in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324358/zero-pad-digits-in-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`str_pad`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.str-pad.php) function of `PHP`

```
$input = 1;
$number = str_pad($input, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 2):

sprintf has this build in:

```
$number = sprintf("%07d", $input)
```