# how to generate reference number like RFC-0001 RFC-0002 RFC-0010 RFC-0101 using php and sql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table in the database contains ID which is the primary key and auto incremented, and RFC the RFC should be auto incremented as well like RFC-0001 then RFC-0002 but on the HTML/PHP part for some reason I'm doing something wrong and I dont know how to fix it any ideas ?
this is my database table

[image]

and this is my php html code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "change";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

?>
<?php
$try="select * from test order by id desc limit1";
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$try);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$lastid= $row['rfc'];
if ($lastid == " ")
{
 $empid ="RFC-0001";
}
else
{
 $empid = substr($lastid, 4);
 $empid= intval($empid);
 $empid= "RFC-".($empid +1);
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="ID" value="<?php echo $empid; ?>"readonly>
</br>
<input type="text" name="name">
</br>
<input type="button" name="done" value="done">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it prints RFC-1 RFC-2 RFC-3 instead of RFC-0001 RFC-0002 which I cant find why

Comment: Because you are converting to an integer, `$empid= intval($empid);` – and integers do not have leading zeros. You need to pad this with zeros again, after you added 1 to the value.

Comment: I have no clue on how to do that can you help me with that @CBroe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324358/zero-pad-digits-in-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$empid= "RFC-".($empid +1);
```

with

```
$empid= "RFC-".sprintf('%04d', ($empid +1));
```

[sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) allows padding a number with zeros