# How to get numbers in range between 001 to 012 in PHP

Tags: php, range

I am trying to get the value between 001 to 012 with range function but it's returning 1,2,3....12
range(001,012)
but i want value like this 001,002,003,,,012

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zero-pad digits in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324358/zero-pad-digits-in-string)

Answer (score 0):

Need to loop through and append them:

```
foreach (range(1, 12) as $number){
  $numbers[] = sprintf("%03d", $number);
}

print_r($numbers);
```